# Redirecting to login page- Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check the session; if it exits it goes to my web site, otherwise redirecting to "login" page; here is my controller:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();
}

public function index($failed=FALSE) {
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_view';
    $data['failed_validation'] = $failed;
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

public function is_logged_in() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('f_name') != null) {
        return;
    } else {
        $this->index();
       //die()// This one does not help either
    }
}

public function display_site() {
    $data['main_content'] = 'site_view';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

This is the version after suggestion(but still the same problem!):

Controller:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    if ($this->user_model->is_logged_in() == FALSE) {
        $this->index();
    }
}

public function index($failed=FALSE) {
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_view';
    $data['failed_validation'] = $failed;
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

public function login() {
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_view';
    $data['failed_validation'] = FALSE;
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
  public function is_logged_in()
    {
         return ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') );
    }
```

Thats fine but when the user goes to logs in page, it shows both login page and my website main page! In other hand even if I die in (see the comment in my code) it does not help, it gives me a blank page!

Thanks

Comment: ideally you should only return true or false from `is_logged_in` it makes not sence otherwise, currently it is not normalised and returns mixed so your code is just wrong, methods in the controller should use as routings, so index is your index, display_site would be /the_controller/display_site you should try and move your logic into a model

Comment: I applied your suggestion(could you please see my edited post); but still the same problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login Controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('includes/login');
    }
}
```

Main Controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();      
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            if (!$this->user_model->is_logged_in()) {
               redirect(base_url().'login', 'location', 301);
            }   
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('includes/main');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see my edited question; I guess this is exactly what I did! Could you please highlight the difference?

Comment: And just need to say that this one does show the login page 2 times; one from constructor and one from index; in other words whenever I redired in costructor it does not stop exeution and since index by deafult gets called, it calles index too!

Comment: you are not redirecting to $this->login() instead you are redirecting to $this->index().. and in index() you have set $data['main_content'] = 'login_view' but logically it should be 'site_view'

Comment: Ummm; now it makes sense; my big mistake was I wanted to implement both login and other things in a same controller! I guess that would not be possible and it makes sense either! I will try yours now!

Comment: Thanks so much Younis! It was great! I have a simple question! So there is no way to have the logic of both login (such as validate_login) and othe stuff od site (such as display_site,...) in the same controller? Right? they should be separated?Right?

Comment: well, there can be a logic if you don't check for $this->user_model->is_logged_in() in constructor, rather check it in index function and then redirect if it is false. But again that won't be a good approach.  A controller should have functions related to that controller only. So it's better to write separate controllers for login and main.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [redirect()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function which is part of the url_helper. Once you have loaded that you can simply call redirect("yoururlhere.com")  Since you might use it often you might want to load it automatically rather than loading the lib every time.